# Scale color error when trying to put a frame in a range with geom_rect over a geom_errorbar in ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

First I will simulate the data I am working with for replication.

```
  electrode <- c('Cz','Fz','Pz')
  value <- c(2.307785,1.613350,2.925053)
  sd <- c(0.7593193,0.7612393,0.7568794)
  se <- c(0.002829816,0.002836971,0.002820723)
  ci <- c(0.005546431,0.005560455,0.005528609)
  tgc <- data.frame(electrode,value,sd,se,ci)

  col <- c("#004d8d", "#cc2701", "#e5b400")
  stdev <- c(10.783939,10.506721,9.415955)
```

See I also specify the color and then use a manual scale in the `ggplot`.

Now if I put the `geom_error`before the `geom_rect` that adds the shade I want, it works fine but it does layer the shade over the points with error bars, as you can see with the `Fz` in the middle.

```
  p1 <- ggplot(tgc, aes(x=factor(electrode), y=value, colour=electrode)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), width=.1, alpha=.5) +
    geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE,mapping =aes(xmin=0, xmax=Inf, ymin=-0.1*min(stdev), ymax=0.1*max(stdev)),fill="grey",alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +   
    scale_fill_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +
    labs(title="Difference at max. discrepancy", x="Electrode", y="Signal (µV)") +
    lims(y = c(-10, 10)) +
    theme_linedraw() +
    geom_point()

  p1
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is change the layer order, and to do so, I interchange places of `geom_rect` with `geom_errorbar`.

```
  p1 <- ggplot(tgc, aes(x=factor(electrode), y=value, colour=electrode)) +
    geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE,mapping =aes(xmin=0, xmax=Inf, ymin=-0.1*min(stdev), ymax=0.1*max(stdev)),fill="grey",alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=value-sd, ymax=value+sd), width=.1, alpha=.5) +
    scale_color_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +   
    scale_fill_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +
    labs(title="Difference at max. discrepancy", x="Electrode", y="Signal (µV)") +
    lims(y = c(-10, 10)) +
    theme_linedraw() +
    geom_point()

  p1
```

And I get the following error message and it does not draw the new plot.

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

And I don't really understand why this is happening as I am, in fact, specifying fill in `geom_rect`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that by switching the order a continuous x scale is "added" to your plot via the `geom_rect` which when adding the `geom_errorbar` raises an error as there you are mapping a categorical variable on `x`. In contrast, doing it the other way around is fine, i.e. we could map a continuous value on an otherwise discrete scale.

A fix would be to explicitly set a discrete x scale by adding a `scale_x_discrete` before the `geom_rect`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(tgc, aes(x = factor(electrode), y = value, colour = electrode)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  geom_rect(inherit.aes = FALSE, mapping = aes(xmin = 0, xmax = Inf, ymin = -0.1 * min(stdev), ymax = 0.1 * max(stdev)), fill = "grey", alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = value - sd, ymax = value + sd), width = .1, alpha = .5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col, breaks = c("Fz", "Cz", "Pz")) +
  labs(title = "Difference at max. discrepancy", x = "Electrode", y = "Signal (µV)") +
  lims(y = c(-10, 10)) +
  theme_linedraw() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Clear as day, thank you stefan!